# is await task equal to throwing the exception of the faulted task in the ContinueWith

Tags: c#, async-await

is the following not redundant?

```
await blob.CopyToBlobAsync(newBlob).
       ContinueWith((t) => { if (t.IsFaulted) throw t.Exception; });
```

as if there was not a ContinueWith call, the exception will be thrown directly?

When would one use continueWith instead of just await a task?

is the following the same ?

```
await myTask.ContinueWith(t => {'do something with the task t'});
```

and

```
await myTask;
'do something with the task MyTask'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ContinueWith(t => { if (t.IsFaulted) throw t.Exception; })` line has different semantics than just `await`ing the `CopyToBlobAsync` task directly:

- It ignores cancellation results; the `Task` returned by `ContinueWith` will complete successfully even if the `Task` returned by `CopyToBlobAsync` is canceled. This may be intentional behavior.
- It ignores successful results; any return value from `CopyToBlobAsync` is dropped.
- It wraps any exceptions in an `AggregateException` by throwing `t.Exception` directly. This  is almost certainly buggy behavior.

So it's not *exactly* redundant, and is *probably* a mistake.

You can use `ContinueWith` in some situations instead of `await`ing a task. In my code, I usually only do this if the continuation is simple, I don't need the context in the continuation, and I don't want the overhead of the `async` state machine. For most situations, you should prefer `await` possibly combined with `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Your last examples are not the same; `ContinueWith` will execute on a thread pool by default, while `await` by default will capture a context and execute the continuation within that context. Also, you have to be very careful how you use the task in your continuation: you usually want exceptions and cancellation propagated to the continuation task, and that's not as easy as it first appears.

In short, I recommend `await` in almost every scenario. It's easier to write, easier to read, and has reasonable default behavior.

Comment: I have a situation, where I create and start tasks in a loop and restrict the number of concurrent running tasks with a semaphore. I continueWith on the tasks and check if they have failed, and if so adds a ID to a ConcurrentBag such I can see if all succeded. I could not get a exception to propergate correctly from my continueWith delegate to my out task, the one that runs the loop. (does this sound stupid, or should add the code for clarification).

Comment: I recommend that you check out TPL Dataflow. It sounds like it would be useful for your scenario.

Comment: A ActionBlock could be interesting for my case. Is it correctly understood that I can define it as the code that need to be run multiply times and just post inputs to it as long as I have inputs.

Comment: That didnt work out so great. The ActionBlock performed correctly, but it processed the data posted to it one by one. My other solution started N tasks concurrently.  Did you want me to read it just for better understanding of TPL or something specific?

Comment: You can use the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` block option; it's set to 1 by default.

Comment: Then I am back to the implementation of Parallel.For i guess? I vent with a semaphore in the first place because Parallel.For was not good at finding how many threads to start. But i will try it.

Comment: Didnt get it to work, need to create a new post about my issue. When i have used CopyToAsync and this ActionBlock with a high number of Parallelism, my stream CopyTo throws exceptions at me. (The streams are coming from ZipArchiveEntry.Open. But thanks for the comments.